# Inequality in probability with discrete random variables

Tags: probability

Does it make any sense? Let X be a non-negative random variable with E[X] > 0. Show that there is ε > 0 such that P(X ≥ ε) ≥ ε.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $P(X \ge \epsilon) < \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$, then $$P(X > 0) = \lim_{\epsilon \downarrow 0} P(X \ge \epsilon) \le \lim_{\epsilon \downarrow 0} \epsilon = 0,$$
so $P(X=0)=1$.

Comment: Sorry sir. Is there an ε > 0 such that P(X ≥ ε) ≥ ε? I couldn’t see that! Thanks.

Comment: @MarcioLassance I am proving the contrapositive: "if such an $\epsilon$ does not exist, then $E[X]=0$."